# Clarification on how Total[] can be used on multi-dimensional array

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, summation, packed-arrays

I have a rank 5 tensor that ultimately I want to modify so that for the first 3 dimensions, each element is summed together. The result will be a rank 2 tensor whose elements are the summed totals from the other 3 dimensions.

That was pretty abstract and difficult for me to explain..

But I believe I can achieve the result that I want by using the function Total[].

I see that I can use Total to sum along a single dimension, or multiple dimensions. I'm just a bit confused about exactly how this works.

Can I simply use:

```
MyArray (*This is the rank 5 tensor*)

Table[MyArray, {1, 2, 3}]; 
(*This is supposed to sum up all elements along indices 1,2,3 , \
leaving behind a rank 2 tensor.*)
```

Are there any issues with this? Should I instead call Total three separate times?

Comment: Have you tried this: `c = ConstantArray[1, {3, 3, 3, 3, 3}]; Total[c, {1, 3}]` ?

Comment: Or `Total[c, 3]`.

Comment: So the only difference between this and what I wrote is that you called the indices {1,3} and I called the indices {1,2,3}. Is that correct? Can you clarify why you made this change?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I see that with that notation Total sums 'down to the level n' per the documentation. For my example, should I sum down to level 2 to end up with a rank 2 tensor? i.e. should it be Total[c, 2] or Total[c, 3]?

Comment: It sums up the first 3 slots. Compare to `a = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, Range[1, 5]];
{Dimensions[a], Dimensions[Total[a, 3]]}`.

Comment: Excellent, I think that is what I want to do. Thanks for the help arnould and henrik!

Comment: @LooseyGoose You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

A good way to test things is to create an array where all the dimensions are different, and then check the dimensions of the result. So:

```
array = ConstantArray[1, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}];
Total[array, 3] //Dimensions
```

> {5, 6}

This shows that [`Total`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total) summed over the first 3 dimensions. Another example:

```
Total[array, {2, 4}] //Dimensions
```

> {2, 6}

showing that the 3 middle dimensions have been summed over.